# Indian evisa form doesn't allow for permanent adress and present adress to be in different countries?

Tags: visas, india, applications

My brother is applying for an Indian evisa. He is a Norwegian citizen who is registered as a resident of Norway in the government register, but he studies in the UK and spends most of the year there.

He wants to put his UK adress as present adress and the Norwegian one as permanent adress. (Is this correct?)

However, the form doesn't seem to allow for these two addresses to be in different countries.

What should he do?

Comment: `For any clarification or doubt may contact to indiatvoa@gov.in` Did you try this ? I know you might not get a reply ever maybe, but worth a try.

Comment: Unless one of the addresses is in Pakistan, I doubt India would care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its could be a subjective question, so I will answer from my view.

As he is a student in UK, living there, and probably wants all the postal communication to be delivered at UK address, it might be safely assumed for this above-said purpose that his residence/current-permanent address is UK one.

Now, residence word has multiple meanings as per context.

- In immigration, it might mean certain fixed number of days which qualify you resident or not. Like, you can not apply for Schengen visa from Qatar as non-Qatari, if you are in country for less than 90 days, or you are on tourist visa, because both these disqualify you from being resident of Qatar.
- For tax purposes, you are indian resident, and thus are supposed to pay tax on your worldwide income to India, if you are in India for at least 182 days of that financial year.
- For certain immigration to UK as EU resident, you are supposed to be living in EU for 6 months and should be working or studying.

As he is going for tourism to India, and his "present" centre of living is in UK (studying, spending most of the year), he might consider putting UK address as both present and permanent address. Note that it is permanent as of now, tomorrow or after 6 months, or 6 years he might move places, and thus permanent address is not permanent-for-life.